# Sort array by rule made of mysql select

Tags: php, arrays, select

Hello everyone I have really chalenging task I have to sort an array by condition with mysql select or by another array. Imagine something like that

```
$arrayINeedToSort = array(5,4,7,96,1,0,55);

// Dont know if it is important cause of next step    
sort($arrayINeedToSort);

$arrayToCheckDuplicData = array();

foreach($arrayINeedToSort as $aid)
{
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM `some_table` WHERE arrayValueId = $aid ");
  $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($num)
  {
     echo $aid;
  }
  else
  {
   // skip this id cause it is not in array but i would like to push at the end of an      array again sorted

     if(in_array($aid,$arrayToCheckDuplicData))
     {
       echo $aid;
     } 
    else
    {
      $arrayINeedToSort[] = $aid; 
     }
     $arrayToCheckDuplicData[] = $aid;
  }
}
```

Thats my idea, pushing array values to the end of acutal array with another simple array check but i am open to different/better ideas.

UPDATE //////////////////////////////////////////////

I need to see all ids so i cant skip them and I need them sorted.

TO BE MORE SPECIFIC i would liek to have input like this

1,4,96 (of values which are in database ) 0,5,7,55 (of values which are not in databse) at the end array will look like this

```
$outputSortedArray(1,4,96,0,5,7,55);
```

Comment: You are not pushing values onto the same array. What is your expected end output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please be more specific in what you want. On what is the input and what you want in your output.

If you need to sort the array $arrayINeedToSort then use sort function.

Give an example of the input and output array. Also the table with condition you wanted to check.

Check the following code and verify if this is what you want:

`

```
$arrayINeedToSort = array(5,4,7,96,1,0,55);

$in_cond = implode(",", $arrayINeedToSort);

$arrayToCheckDuplicData = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM `some_table` WHERE arrayValueId IN (" . $in_cond . ") ORDER BY arrayValueId ASC");

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if (in_array($row["arrayValueId"], $arrayINeedToSort)) {
    echo $row["arrayValueId"];
  }
  else {
    if (in_array($row["arrayValueId"], $arrayToCheckDuplicData)) {
      echo $row["arrayValueId"];
    }
    $arrayToCheckDuplicData[] = $row["arrayValueId"];
  }
}
```

`

Comment: with little edit yes ;) your solution is faster and safer i think ill try both ways thank you

Comment: Please upvote if you liked the solution and found the answer useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php array sorting functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
There is also a function called array_unique, which is delete multiple values from an array.

If you want to sort the array in the MySQL query, use "ORDER BY ASC/DESC".